# CSS properties not showing up in ClojureScript

Tags: css, dom, clojurescript

I have a dom element (div) with some css properties like background-color, padding etc., which I'm trying to access like so:

```
(prn (-> my-dom-element .-style .-background-color))
```

But this is printing nil. However, just doing:

```
(prn (-> my-dom-element .-style))
```

does print the expected `#object[CSSStyleDeclaration [object CSSStyleDeclaration]]`

What am I doing wrong?

-- Edit --

I've tried `(prn (gs/getStyle my-dom-element "background-color"))` with `(:require [goog.style :as gs])`, but that prints the empty string. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

`background-color` is not a valid JS property name since it would literally be `background - color` (MINUS). The compiler always munges that to `background_color` to make it valid JS, which of course is no longer a valid CSS name.

However since JS has the same issue the style property names use camelCase notation so the proper name would be `backgroundColor`.

You can use `(gs/getStyle my-dom-element "background-color")` with `(:require [goog.style :as gs])` in your `ns` which will take care of converting the property name.

Comment: That didn't work for me. It doesn't give nil anymore, but I get the empty string instead.  Furthermore, it's not like (prn (-> my-dom-element .-style .-color)) was working (gives empty string) which doesn't have the property name issue.

Comment: The `style` object only returns values if you have actually set them via `style` in the first place. If the style comes from a CSS class you can use `(gs/getComputedStyle elm "background-color")`.